# Remove yellow line through box shadow

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a small project that's supposed to be a button on a bus, here's a picture to show what I mean:

[image]

You can see on the stop button that I'm using a box shadow, and that there's a yellow line right through the shadow and I was wondering if there's any way to remove it?

This is my CSS code:

```
#Stick {
    width: 90px;
    height: 700px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: grey;
    border-radius: 0%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 1150px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
#ButtonShell {
    width: 120px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: ;
    margin-top: -450px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 1135px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
#Button {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    background: red;
    border-radius: ;
    margin-top: -135px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 1160px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 5px red;
}
#ButtonText {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Adobe Text Pro;
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 11px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
<div id="Stick"></div>
<div id="ButtonShell"></div>
<div id="Button">
    <p id="ButtonText">STOP</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this from your code `border: 1px solid yellow;` from `#Button`

```css
#Stick {
   width: 90px;
   height: 700px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   background: grey;
   border-radius: 0%;
   margin-top: -10px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   margin-left: 1150px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}
#ButtonShell {
   width: 120px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   background: yellow;
   border-radius: ;
   margin-top: -450px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   margin-left: 1135px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}
#Button {
   width: 70px;
   height: 70px;
   
   background: red;
   border-radius: ;
   margin-top: -135px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   margin-left: 1160px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 5px red;
}
#ButtonText {
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: Adobe Text Pro;
   margin-top: 24px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   margin-left: 11px;
   margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Stick"></div>
<div id="ButtonShell"></div>
<div id="Button">
<p id="ButtonText">STOP</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh sorry I totally missed that, thanks it worked ! XD